# Android: Adding Text to an ImageButton?

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

How can I add `text` to an `ImageButton`?

In my application I want to add `text` to each of my three `ImageButtons` to let the user know what game each opens.

E.g. adding "Maths Games" to the first Circular `ImageButton` shown in screenshot below:

[image]

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/ibFirstTabMaths"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mathsicon"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
             android:id="@+id/ibFirstTabMemory"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/memoryicontwo"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/ibFirstTabStroop"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/stroopicon"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="@color/GrayLight"
            app:border_width="4dp"
            app:shadow="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Activity Code:**

```
public class firstActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Declare vars
    CircularImageView ibMaths;
    CircularImageView ibMemory;
    CircularImageView ibStroop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_tab);

        initialiseVars();

    }

    public void initialiseVars() {

        ibMaths = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibFirstTabMaths);

        ibMemory = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibFirstTabMemory);

        ibStroop = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.ibFirstTabStroop);

        // set on click listeners for the buttons
        ibMaths.setOnClickListener(this);
        ibMemory.setOnClickListener(this);
        ibStroop.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.ibFirstTabMaths:

            Intent openMathsGame = new Intent("com.example.brianapp.meditation");
            // Start activity
            startActivity(openMathsGame);

            break;

        case R.id.ibFirstTabMemory:

            Intent openMemGame = new Intent("com.example.brianapp.MemoryGame");

            // Start activity
            startActivity(openMemGame);

            break;

        case R.id.ibFirstTabStroop:

            // change this to make sure it opens the med screen
            Intent openStroopGame = new Intent("com.example.brianapp.Stroop");
            // Start activity
            startActivity(openStroopGame);

            break;

        }// switch end

    }

}
```

Comment: You could always make a `RelativeLayout` and inside it you put your `CircularImageView` occupying the all layout. Next, you just put 3 or 4 `TextViews` inside the same `RelativeLayout`. Then, you only have to make a `OnClickListener` to that `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, there must be an easier way to do so?

Comment: if you want to give text then why your not using button?
second still you want text to image button then you can create image of that text and set that image to that image button :)

Comment: You can put textView under each image button or do like "Android is everything for me" sayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are create custom view for your ImageView so you can use canvas to do this.
on draw method get canvas and drawtext on center of view.

main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/packageName"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <packageName.ImgBtn
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:text="your text here or in String.xml as reference"
    android:src="@drawable/bookmark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomWidgetAttr" >
       <attr name="text" format="string|reference"/>
       <attr name="pic" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

ImgBtn.class

```
public class ImgBtn extends ImageButton {
private String Text;
private Drawable Logo;
private Paint paint;

public ImgBtn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomWidgetAttr);

    Text = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.CustomWidgetAttr_text);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int w = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    int h = this.getMeasuredHeight();

    canvas.drawText(Text, w/2, h/2, paint);

}

}
```

complete code here ;)

Comment: This sounds like what I need to do, Can you please post an example of code so that I can accept the answer. thanks

Comment: This is a really bad implementation. The text is positioned inside the image and, at around 3dp in size, is unreadable. Also,after converting all the ImageButtons in my toolbar to the custom image buttons, the toolbar ended up taking over the entire view.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create image with Text and use it as source of Imagebutton and provide background as null . For example

```
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/image_with_text"
```

Comment: Thanks, will this keep the image within the button also?